# Mathematical induction in the second step of proof of $1 + a + a^2 +.. + a^{n-1} = \frac{a^n-1}{a - 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am desperate for help, and far away from my institution and I had a tough time finding anything specific to my problem.

I need to prove the following:

$1 + a + a^2 +.. + a^{n-1} = \frac{a^n-1}{a - 1}$

And I am just confused how I go from here:

$\frac{a^n-1}{a-1} + a^{n+1}$ to  $\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$.

Comment: You have confused your exponents.  The term after $a^{n-1}$ is $a^n$ not $a^{n+1}$ as you have written it above.

Comment: @Danny Delic: Recall $x + \frac{y}{z} = \frac{x z + y}{z}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**  if you look carefully at the statement, it says the sum with n terms raise the n-th power of $a$. Count the number of terms in the sum carefully and you should have

$$1+a+a^2+...+a^n+a^{n+1}=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}+\frac{(a-1)a^{n+1}}{a-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove by induction, start with the basis step (I guess you've probably done this)

$P(1): 1 = \frac{a^1 - 1}{a -1}$

which is true. For the induction hypothesis, we assume the result holds for $P(k)$

$P(k): 1 + a + a^2 + ... + a^{k-1} = \frac{a^k - 1}{a - 1}$

We want to prove that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$, so

$1 + a + a^2 + ... + a^{k-1} + a^k = \frac{a^k - 1}{a - 1} + a^k \text{ (by induction hypothesis)}$

$\begin{align}
\frac{a^k - 1}{a - 1} + \frac{a^k(a-1)}{a - 1} &= \frac{a^{k+1} +a^k - a^k - 1}{a - 1}\\
&=\frac{a^{k + 1} - 1}{a - 1}
\end{align}$

which is in the required form. Hence $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ and the result follows.